# How to handle when a function to a function returns multiple results instead of one

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm a bit of a powershell novice but this works if I have one notepad window open, but if I have two notepad windows open, it fails.

```
$appName = "notepad"
Write-Host "Getting run time for" $appName
New-TimeSpan -Start (get-process $appName).StartTime |select Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds
```

It fails because `get-process $appName` returns two results. How can I re-format this code to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for one or multiple instances:

```
Get-Process $appname | % {new-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime} | select Days,Hours,Minutes,Seconds
```

`Get-Process` forwards the objects through the pipeline, for each item (`% {}`) we create a timespan object.